# BlackBerry - hide virtual keyboard on a Screen that does not extend MainScreen

Tags: java, blackberry, hide, virtual-keyboard

Edit:
I know how to [hide virtual keyboard on a MainScreen](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Hide_touch_screen_keyboard_new_screen_508172_11.jsp) (when working with SpinboxField), but I can't hide it when working with a subclass of Screen.

Comment: found the answer: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TextSpinBoxField.html

Comment: If that's the answer, I don't think you asked the right question.

Comment: got it! I must be clearer when asking questions. ...my bad. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getScreen().getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE)` -- with appropriate null checks after getScreen and getVirtualKeyboard, of course.

Note that this is only possible if you're targeting 4.7 or later -- if you want to support older platforms, you'll need a separate build without this code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use too

```
getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE_FORCE);
```

> HIDE_FORCE indicates the keyboard
>   should always be hidden when the
>   context has focus, and that displaying
>   the keyboard should not be permitted.

```
getVirtualKeyboard().setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE)
```

> HIDE indicates the keyboard should be
>   hidden either the next time the
>   context has focus, or immediately if
>   the context is already has focus.
>   Subsequently, the visibility state
>   should be automatically saved and
>   restored.